# NDB - attribute as a list

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Creating a webapp where students are able to sign up for courses. So far, the **Course** model has attributes:
  - Teacher
  - Course Name
  - Date Created

And the **Student** model has attributes:
  - Name
  - email (unique)

I would like to be able to add a student list to a particular course. i.e. Jim, John, and Bob are all a part of Math101. Would it make more sense to structure the **Course** model with a list of students or give each student a list of courses they are a part of?

Either way, how could I structure the models? I am having a tough time wrapping my head around the idea of doing it without creating a new entry in the datastore.

Comment: I think you do need a new model. One with keys to both Student and Class models. In that model you can also store things like start- and end-date of the class, etc.

Comment: Agreed.  You will fnd all sorts of course enrollment details are probably needed down the track.  Store enough details of the course and the student in this entity so that you can perform all of the queries you might need on this entity directly.  (I have implemented a system with 4000+ students 5+ years ago on appengine using this approach.)